# Updation of values of Array within a range

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a array[1:N], which is initialized as MAXIMUM-VALUE.

I have to maintain a system where each user/bidder gives the range(low,high) of elements and its bid for each element of that range.  His bid value for each element within this range is same. I have to get minimum bid made for all different elements. After some bids, I have to get the values of the array.

I have written a code but it runs in O(n^2).

```
while(number_of_bids--)
{
    cin>>low>>high>>bid_value;
    while(low<=high && low<=N)
    {   
        vs[low].cost=min(vs[low].cost,bid_value);
        low++;
    }
}
```

Example if the for array[1:10], and the bids are :

```
1 2 65
2 4 58
3 7 86
1 9 88
```

then value of array becomes :

> 65, 58, 58, 58, 86, 86, 86, 88, 88, MAXIMUM-VALUE

Please suggest any algorithm which improves the time complexity.

Comment: How did you arrive at `O(n^2)` ?

Comment: Because number_of_bids has  a range of 1:N, and 1 <= low <= N, and 1<= high <= N. So my worst case complexity will be O(N^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using structure and Mapping of indices.
Here is the explanation:
First construct a array/vector of structure of ranges and bids.
As:

```
struct node{
 int bid;
 int left;
 int right;
}arr[10005];
```

Now take the input of bids in the array. Then sort the array, using a comparator on bid.
As:

```
sort(arr,arr+n,comp)
// comparator function could be as :
bool comp(node c,node d)
{
return c.bid<d.bid;
}
```

Now make an auxilary array for mapping the indices and initialize it by -1. Then traverse the structure array and fill the auxilary array to the right no. As:

```
int flag=0,count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 flag=arr[i].left;
 while(flag<n && flag<=arr[i].right){
 if(aux_array[flag]==-1){
   aux_array[flag] = arr[i].right;
  flag++;count++;
  }
  else {
     flag=aux_array[flag]+1;
   }
   if(count>=n) break;
  }
 if(count>=n) break;
}
```

Now, you are done.

Comment: Nice! It has the same complexity as my solution, but is simpler and propably performs better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(N*lg N)` using a balanced binary tree (an ordered set in c++ or Java).

First of all prepare a list of events of the form: "index: the i-th bid starts" or "index: the k-th bid ends" (index is either the low or high part of range). Sort the list by the index.

Create a tree to store bids that is ordered by the bid value.

Traverse the array from left to right. Whenever there is an event (or events) for current cell in the array (the events are stored in a separate sorted list) add or remove the bid referred in the event from the tree. For each cell find the minimum bid in the tree. Store this value in the cell. If the tree is empty leave the cell with `MAXIMUM-VALUE`.

One subtlety here is to handle bid duplicates. You can store only the bid values (without ranges) in the tree, however your data structure has to allow duplicates (a multiset), and when removing a bid be sure to remove only one occurrence of that value. Alternatively, you can store distinct bid identifiers like their position in the input, but order the tree by the bid values.

Let `N` be the size of your array and `M` be the number of bids.

This algorithm gives you worst case `O(N*lg M + M*lg M)` time.

Sorting of bid events is obviously `O(M*lg M)`.

Then the main loop has `O(N)` iterations (the size of the array), and for each cell we do a single lookup to find the smallest bid which is `O(lg M)`.

We also have to process `O(M)` events like adding or removing bids, each of which also takes `O(lg M)` time.

With the assumption that the number of bids `M` is `O(N)` (only with this assumption your solution is `O(N^2)`), altogether the algorithm is `O(N*lg N)`.